# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int, How do I resolve this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the code that created the table.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
    Customer_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CHECK(Customer_ID <= 11),
    First_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name varchar(30),
    Home_Street varchar(30),
    Home_City varchar(20),
    Home_State varchar(2),
    Home_Zip varchar(5),
    PhoneNumber varchar(11) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMERS PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID);
```

Then I try to insert data (using this code) into the table and that is where I get this error.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CUSTOMERS(Customer_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Home_Street, Home_City, Home_State, Home_Zip, PhoneNumber)
VALUES (11223344556, 'John', 'Doe', '1234 Hand Street', 'Wahiawa', 'HI', 96786, 2535551267);
```

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server management studio.

Comment: Home_Zip and Phonenumber are VARCHAR , so you need to enclose the values in quotes ,e,g,'96786','2535551267')

Comment: `Customer_ID` is an int. The largest number it can contain is 2147483647. You're trying to insert something longer than that (and, to boot, you have a `CHECK` constraint that means the only positive numbers it will accept are 1-11)

Comment: So using CHECK function will only allow me to use numbers 1-10? I'm still trying to understand what I'm doing. I'm trying to set the int to 11. I thought what I was doing limited it to 11 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS per my understanding you are checking length of `Customer_ID <=11` so you should mention   `len(Customer_ID)<=11`   it will work and you should alter datatype of Customer_ID  `int` to `bigint`

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
    (
    Customer_ID bigINT NOT NULL,
    CHECK(len(Customer_ID)<=11),
    First_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name varchar(30),
    Home_Street varchar(30),
    Home_City varchar(20),
    Home_State varchar(2),
    Home_Zip varchar(5),
    PhoneNumber varchar(11) NOT NULL
    );
    ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMERS
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID);

    INSERT INTO dbo.CUSTOMERS(Customer_ID,First_Name,Last_Name,Home_Street,
    Home_City,Home_State,Home_Zip,PhoneNumber)
    VALUES(11223344556,'John','Doe','1234 Hand Street', 
    'Wahiawa','HI',96786,2535551267);
```

Comment: @Icodin my answer was first and correct. Thank you for marking later posted same answer as right.

Answer (score 1):

You need customer id to be **bigint:**

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(
Customer_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
CHECK(Customer_ID<=11),
First_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Last_Name varchar(30),
Home_Street varchar(30),
Home_City varchar(20),
Home_State varchar(2),
Home_Zip varchar(5),
PhoneNumber varchar(11) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMERS
PRIMARY KEY(Customer_ID);
```

Comment: how this answer will be correct still after seeing my answer you are not getting what i wrote check it once and comment

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to CHECK(Customer_ID<=11) since Customer_ID id integer datatype the server may check for integer validation and not length validation. Try to change the validation.